# GRAILS + Spring Security Plugin --- password is not encrypted when adding users

Tags: grails, spring-security, password-encryption

Clean installation of Grails 3.2.9 + Spring Security Plugin 3.1.0.

Default User/Role/UserRole domains created by `s2-quickstart com.raf.app User Role`.

BootStrap init code:

```
...
def init = { servletContext ->
    def adminRole = Role.findOrSaveWhere(authority: 'ROLE_ADMIN')
    def user = User.findOrSaveWhere(username: 'raf',
            password: 'password')
    if (!user.authorities.contains(adminRole)){
        UserRole.create(user, adminRole)
    }
...
```

I saw in a tutorial that the password for this user should appear encoded in the db (using dbconsole to check this out), but in my case it does not (it's just 'password' like in here).

So I went to the User domain and made these horrible changes:

```
def beforeUpdate() {
        encodePassword()
    }

    protected void encodePassword() {
        password = springSecurityService?.passwordEncoder ? springSecurityService.encodePassword(password) : springSecurityService.encodePassword(password)
    }
```

And this on the other hand throws NullPointer exception. Why?

```
 Cannot invoke method encodePassword() on null object
```

So what do I do to have my passwords encrypted, like I like 'em?

Comment: **Do not encrypt passwords**, when the attacker gets the DB he will also get the encryption key. Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security.  Iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use a function such as `ehash`, `PBKDF2`, `Bcrypt` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: @zaph I think Rafai has simply repeated existing code over where it had failed to run the default encryption method. I think you need to look into spring security a bit more since there are no keys on a db table :)

Comment: Encryption with no key!

Comment: Thanks for your comment zaph, but it's too abstract for me now, hopefully I'll be able to understand it thoroughly before production. :D

Comment: The security of user passwords is important to the users, important enough for developers to understand how they are protected. In a similar manor a structural engineer needs to understand how the bridge is built, wood or steel, that level of understanding is one of the attributes of a professional.

Comment: @zaph Of course. I'm trying to build my first ever web-app. If you have any tips/sources on how to improve in these areas, feel free to share.

Comment: @vahid Quite true that I don't understand the security details of spring security, certainly I do not understand encryption with no key! Could point me to a good source of spring security information? The point is that with encryption the original password is available, with hashing it is not. In general the terms password and encryption do not belong together and when used together raise a red flag.

Comment: https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/tree/master/src/docs/passwords you can take a read here Burt would probably best have an answer for you. I did read somewhere there is some dynamics in the way it encrypted as in per record..(using something in user domain object) as the dynamic addition to crypt/decryot,,,it was long ago hazy memories.,,

Comment: The spring security configuration setup by default in Grails uses Bcrypt

Comment: @JamesKleeh Great, Bcrypt is a secure method, can you provide a link?

Comment: @zaph https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v3/index.html#passwords You can see the default value is Bcrypt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I believe the NullPointer was caused by what vahid described.

However, to have my passwords encoded by default, I had to set

```
autowire: true
```

in Configs/application.yml. Don't ask me why, but it works.

Comment: Starting with Grails 3.2.8, autowiring of Gorm entities is disabled when you create an application from scratch. I.e., the recommendation is to not inject services into domain classes. Query 1000 records that are mapped into Gorm entities, and you pay a performance hit of having the service injected into 1000 Gorm entities. You can alter that behavior with the change to application.yml as you found.  
Source: Grails Team Blog, 09 May 2017.

Answer (score 1):

So to explain what is going on in the hope it makes more sense

You have simply told the code to repeat the encrypt function if it cant find encode.

Above code by default is here

```
 password = springSecurityService?.passwordEncoder ? springSecurityService.encodePassword(password) : password
```

This says :

```
if (springSecurityService?.passwordEncoder) {
springSecurityService.encodePassword(password) 
} else {
password
}
```

So you see you have told it to do what it can't

I am  on grails 3.2.8 and using:

```
compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.1.2'
```

Comment: I changed this code after I noticed no encryption of the password, because I thought that the ternary's operator 'no' was being evaluated ('password', not the 'yes' branch witch encryption). Ok, so I was wrong about meaning of this code and it explains the NullPointer. But why are my passwords not encrypted?

Comment: thats where the problem resides it cant get hold of springSecurityService.passwordEncoder I left he version I am currently using and works for me on 3.2.8. So perhaps it is related to the version you are using in your build.gradle.

Answer (score 1):

If you setup Spring Security manually insted of using the command provided. Maybe you forgot to add the `UserPasswordEncoderListener` class and define it in `resources.groovy` as a bean. This class should encode the password automaticly

---

**UserPasswordEncoderListener:**

```
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityService
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic
import org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.Datastore
import org.grails.datastore.mapping.engine.event.*
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationEvent

@CompileStatic
class UserPasswordEncoderListener extends AbstractPersistenceEventListener {

    @Autowired
    SpringSecurityService springSecurityService

    UserPasswordEncoderListener(final Datastore datastore) {
        super(datastore)
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPersistenceEvent(AbstractPersistenceEvent event) {
        if (event.entityObject instanceof User) {
            User u = (event.entityObject as User)
            if (u.password && (event.eventType == EventType.PreInsert || (event.eventType == EventType.PreUpdate && u.isDirty('password')))) {
                event.getEntityAccess().setProperty("password", encodePassword(u.password))
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    boolean supportsEventType(Class<? extends ApplicationEvent> eventType) {
        eventType == PreUpdateEvent || eventType == PreInsertEvent
    }

    private String encodePassword(String password) {
        springSecurityService?.passwordEncoder ? springSecurityService.encodePassword(password) : password
    }
}
```

---

**resources.groovy**

```
beans = {
    userPasswordEncoderListener(UserPasswordEncoderListener, ref('hibernateDatastore'))
}
```

---

`UserPasswordEncoderListener` should be placed under `src/main/groovy/com.mypackage...`